# How do I pass along an index specific prop?

Tags: react-native, react-props, react-state

This is the code for the '+1' for each item in a flatlist. When the item is clicked, they each have their individual count. How do i acccess this count outside of the counter class? I can't figure out how to pass it along so as it is index specific?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        bgColor: [
          '#7ED3EB',
          
          '#FF9191',
          '#B25E9D',
          '#093A52',
          '#FFA87C',
          '#781330',
          '#BAB3F2',
          '#C2A0E0',
          '#BF3D35',
          '#8ADFF2',
          '#49C144',
          '#135088',
          '#8053AE',
          '#94BEA1',
          '#93D9B4',
          '#F66955',
          '#F08346'


        ],
        selectedColor: '',
        count: 0,
    }}

  addCount = () => {
    let newCount = this.state.count + 1;
      console.log(this.state.count)
      console.log(this.props.list.title)

      this.setState({
      count: newCount
    }

    );


  };
```

This below renderitem is what is getting pushed to the flatlist.

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
const list = this.props.list
return (

         

            <CounterButton list={item} newcount={this.state.count} updateList={this.props.updateList}  />
            

)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

create `newCount` variable in global scope or inside `this.state = {}` add `newCount : 0`.
Then it's very easy to achieve what you want.

Comment: from there would it just be best to use a map function to break into components?